# Filtering Trace events from Azure Functions Application Insights

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

Im trying to filter out events such as

1. Posting invocation id:*** on workerId:***
2. Executing 'Functions.***' (Reason='This function was
   programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=***)
3. Executed 'Functions.***' (Succeeded, Id=***)
4. Request successfully matched the route with name '***' and template '/***/{***}'

from App Insights (.net 5 isolated).

the json config is as follows, this has reduced the amount of emitted info but I would like to go further.

```
"logLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "***.***": "Information",
        "Host.Controllers.Host": "Warning",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.Rpc.RpcFunctionInvocationDispatcher": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.WorkerFunctionInvoker": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs": "Warning",
        "Functions.***": "Information",
        "RequestMatchedRoute": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteBase": "Warning"
```

*** *are to obscure real names here not actual settings*

Comment: A thought (does not give the answer to your question) -  Right now you are doing blacklisting of namespaces, instead of that you can set the `Default` to higher log level and start whitelisting namespaces with required logLevel as you need.